# How to update numeric data at two rows in laravel mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a details table in the database which has numbers of rows.

see the image below. which as two rows having **1250, 1250** rupees in the column.
I have shown **2500** in total. but when the user wants to use full total amount I want to update the data in the two columns, How can I update those two rows in laravel?

[image]

```php
$wallet_details = tbl_wallet_detail::where('wd_parent_id', $usewallet->wm_id)
    ->whereMonth('tbl_wallet_details.wd_start_date', date('m'))
    ->whereYear('tbl_wallet_details.wd_start_date', date('Y'))->first();

$wallet_details->wd_used_amount = $wallet_details->wd_used_amount + $request->usewallet;
$wallet_details->wd_remaining_amount = $wallet_details->wd_remaining_amount - $request->usewallet;
$wallet_details->save();
```

Comment: You need some way of identifying those rows, either using a unique ID, or a relationship to your `User` (perhaps a `user_id` or an `order_id`). Once you're able to obtain the relevant rows you can just get them from your database and update them.

Comment: Yes sir. I do know these rows. even I can get those rows. but suppose two rows total amount is (1250,1250) 2500 and user has used 1500 from his account and then the remaining amount is 1000. I want to update and distribute that particular 1000 remaining amount into those two rows.

Answer (score 0):

> suppose two rows total amount is (1250,1250) 2500 and user has used 1500 from his account and then the remaining amount is 1000. I want to update and distribute that particular 1000 remaining amount into those two rows

I don't know all the specifics for your use case (such as how you obtain how much a `User` has already used), however, the following outlines one way of tackling your problem.

I've created a `Wallet` model and associated table for this example and defined a `used` column on it to represent the used amount and similarly a `remaining` column. You'd replace these things with your specifics obviously.

```
$wallet = \App\Models\Wallet::where('user_id', 1)
    ->selectRaw('sum(used) as total')
    ->groupBy('used')
    ->first();

$remaining = $wallet->total - 1500;

\App\Models\Wallet::where('user_id', 1)
    ->update([
        'remaining' => $remaining / $wallet->count()
    ]);
```

1. First we run a query to `sum` (total) the `used` field values for a given `User`
2. Next we calculate the `$remaining` amount by deducting the already used amount (1500 in your example) from the total we obtain in step 1
3. Finally we update the `remaining` columns in the table for each of the rows for the given `User`

As mentioned, how you obtain the relevant rows from the table is down to you, using a `user_id` is just an example but you might use a `transaction id` or whatever makes sense for your use case.